# Where do HTTP request cookies originate?

Tags: cookies, http-headers, httprequest, cloudflare

I have a VB.NET app that sends a POST request to a script on my server that is running Cloudflare. I always get an error when sending the request from the app, however using a Firefox extension to simulate the request works fine. With the use of Fiddler I think I have found the cause of the problem:

**When sending the request with the Firefox addon an extra header is attached to the request:**

> Cookie: __cfduidxxxxxxxxxxxx

This cookie is from Cloudflare, but where does it come from, ie. how can I get this cookie value and send it with my requests from the VB app? I tried copying and pasting the cookie into the app and it worked fine, so this leads me to conclude that I need this cookie, however this value is unique for each user so I cannot simply hardcode it into the app.

Quick side-note: Not sure if this helps, but if I send a GET request from the VB app it works fine without the __cfduid cookie.

Comment: is this in the firefox->site request, or the server->firefox response? If it's in the response, then it's an invalid cookie. Not particularly good for a request either, since it should be more like `key=value`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, apologies for my lack of knowledge in this field. I can see the cookie in the HTTP REQUEST header, ie when I send the request to the server

Comment: The server should be sending back a Set-Cookie: http header - that's the value that gets sent back on the Cookie: header, right? Can't you just strip that value and send it back on your requests?

Comment: Ahh, I see that it works without the Cookie - it could be sending a different cookie (from a different request/server) along. You should see a Set-Cookie: with the same value coming from *somewhere*. Try clearing all the cookies and re-trying.

Comment: @Kylar thank you for your suggestion, once I cleared cookies it didn't work with the firefox addon as I got the 502 error, but in the response I found the set-cookie header which allowed the 2nd request to work perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a `Set-Cookie` header coming back from the server on it's response. It will expect to get that value back on subsequent requests in a `Cookie:` header. This value is usually an opaque string that is classified by a path, although not always.